# vs2017 compile error: double inclusion of header boost/config/abi_prefix.hpp

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2017

I upgraded some vc2008 projects into vc2017 projects, and replaced boost_1_47 with boost_1_64.

Vc2008 projects were correctly compiled, but vc2017 projects reported an error:

```
fatal error C1189: double inclusion of header boost/config/abi_prefix.hpp is an error
```

what does it means? And how to solve it?

I used VS2017 with vc141 toolset and windows 10 SDK

Comment: I am getting this error when including `#include <boost/pool/simple_segregated_storage.hpp>` in a large project. Linux Boost 1.64.